# Service receives api calls from different Azure ip's on “Standard-website”

Tags: azure

We are running a Medium Standard Website instance, and on this we have a few webshops, when the customer tries to capture funds(API call to payment gateway) it sometimes shifts ips, and we need to add the new ip(s) to the gateways approved ip range.

Any ideas why it shifts and is there a way to lock the ip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Websites is website-as-a-service. As such, it's a very large multi-tenant service without dedicated outbound IP addresses. Even if you use your own VMs (e.g. when running Standard as you are currently doing). True, all of your websites are running on reserved VMs, but... your traffic still gets routed through the service itself.

You *can* have dedicated inbound IP addresses if you set up SSL, but that won't help on your outbound IP need.

To answer your question on locking the IP: You'd need to originate your external API call from either a web/worker role instance in a Cloud Service, or from a Virtual Machine, either of which has a static VIP. Note that, if you actually tear down the deployment, you're at risk of losing the assigned IP address (though with Virtual Machines you can shut down and ask for the IP to remain allocated). Also, you now have an option of assigning a non-changing VIP to a deployment.

There are several ways to have your website communicate with a web/worker instance or virtual machine, which I consider out of scope for this question, but you should easily be able to find a bunch of info on queues, vnets, etc.

Comment: Arh okay, thank you for a good and solid explanation. Ive been working a few times with cloud service so i think ill look into this instead. Again thank you

Comment: You don't need to stop using websites (although that's always an option). My point was that you can have your website working along with a role instance or a virtual machine. You have lots of choices.

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/fd53afb7-14b8-41ca-bfcb-305bdeea413e/maintenance-notice-upcoming-changes-to-increase-capacity-for-outbound-network-calls?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview for the list of IP addresses that can be used for outgoing connections from Azure websites.